# Create an array using boolean filtering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This may be a very simple question but I don't know what is the best python-way to do it.

Let say I have an array a, and filter_array f, I would like to create array c.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
f = [True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]
c = [1,"" ,"" ,"" , 5, 6,"" , 8,"" ]
```

*I want "" when False

How can I get c?? Notice I don't want `[1,5,6,8]`

Many thanks

Comment: Arrays or lists? And what do you want to be between the commas?

Comment: `[1, , , , 5, 6, , 8, ]` is an invalid syntax in python

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that it is not valid, I simply wants nothing when it is false, so NaN or ""

Comment: There is no such thing as "nothing," and you have to be explicit about whether you want "" (an array of strings) or nan (an array of numbers).

Comment: I understand now, even None itself will output 'None' on the screen, so I should have decided something for this 'nothing'. I believe empty string "" is the best for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want a blank string between your elements, which will mean it's a string array in the end. If that's the case, you can do:

```
c = np.where(f,a,'')

>>> c
array(['1', '', '', '', '5', '6', '', '8', ''], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Wonderful! Python is such a beautiful language! I didn't know that I can use .where in this case, thanks for your precise answer!

Comment: However, with this code Work["Result"]=pd.np.where(Filter,Work.Time,""), I actually received a warning, SettingWithCopyWarning, A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead, which I don't want to ignore. Work["Result] is a new column that I created at the time I called this line, so it was not existed before. I don't quite understand how the chained assignment works in here, I have also tried to use a temp var in between for a local copy before assigned to Work["Result"], but the result is the same.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure, because I don't get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` in that scenario (I just made up a dataframe to check). But for what you're trying to do, you could also try: `Work.loc[Filter,'Result'] = Work.Time`, followed by `Work.Result.fillna('',inplace=True)`

Comment: I am still getting this warning, I think the problem happens when I try to create this new column 'Result' from the existing Work DataFrame

Comment: So without seeing your code, it's a bit hard to diagnose, but my best guess is that `Work` is copy of something. Did you obtain it using `loc` somewhere else in your code? For a nice overview of how to deal with `SettingWithCopyWarning`, you can take a look at [this blog post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)

Comment: Thanks for following up. DataFrame Work is indeed a copy of a master DataFrame Data, it is a collection of time data within the same day, Work = data[(data.Date == data.Date[SelectedDateIndex[0]]) & (data.index>=SelectedDateIndex[0])], I have changed it to  Work = data.loc[(data.Date == data.Date[SelectedDateIndex[0]]) & (data.index>=SelectedDateIndex[0]),:] but it doesn't help, still the same warning

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use `zip` and evaluate from there

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
f = [True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]

x = list(zip(a, f))
c = [i[0] if i[1] == True else '' for i in x]
```

> ```
> :~/python/stack$ python3.7 sum.py 
> [1, '', '', '', 5, 6, '', 8, '']
> ```

Comment: These are not even arrays.

Comment: @DYZ oh wow its numpy arrays ... smh

Comment: It is not clear what the OP requested. They have a numpy tag, but the arrays look like lists. What they show as expected ouput is illegal in Python. It is always a good idea to wait for a clarification.

Comment: @DYZ yeah I just looked and assumed, but you know they say if you assume you make a 'ass' out of 'u' and 'me' :)

Comment: sorry that I was not aware it is invalid, as I don't know what I can have, NaN or "" or something else. Anyway there are a few solutions now but they all result in the same warning SettingWithCopyWarning when I create a new column on top of the existing DataFrame, can you give any advice on what to do to clear it please? *I tried .loc as suggested but results in the same warning!

Comment: @Victor sorry you will have to defer to someone else I'm relatively new and havent got into df yet

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer using list comprehension:

```
c = [a if f[i] else None for i, a in enumerate(a)]
```

(and you can substitute `None` for whatever you want to put in commas)

Answer (score 1):

As you have not mentioned what you want to store in array when its `False`. So implicitly i am storing `''` i.e *empty string*

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
f = [True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]
replaceBy = ""    # simply replaces by empty string if found false
c = [x if y else replaceBy for (x, y) in zip(a, f)]
print(c)    # [1, '', '' ,'', 5, 6, '', 8, '']
```

If you want to store something different in place of empty string then assign the value to `replaceBy`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I should have stated clearly what the result should be when False, as I actually not clear what choice I could have, either NaN or ""

Comment: use string ie `""` . It will be easy to extract info using try/except

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat hard to interpret but looks like you want to convert one NumPy array into another NumPy array by using a boolean list or array as a mask. This can be accomplished with one call to `np.where`.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
f = [True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]

np.where(f, a, np.nan)
#array([ 1., nan, nan, nan,  5.,  6., nan,  8., nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy masked arrays:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.ma.array(a,mask=np.invert(f));
```

Comment: Many thanks! I need to do some digging to understand the operation of this code. Anyway I have used it to create a new column on top of the existing Work DataFrame, Work["Result"] = np.ma.array(Work.Time,mask=np.invert(Filter)), and I get the warning of SettingWithCopyWarning, *I tried .loc as suggested but results in the same warning! I believe the problem happens when I create the column Result, what can I do to clear it please?

Comment: Can you try keyword copy after mask with value true i.e. (...,copy = True)?